# Dont load dll files to Ninject Kernel

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dll, ninject.web.mvc

I Use Ninject For DIP in My Mvc App and I work with it but I want to Load Some dll Files into My Ninject Kernel in ReportController with below code:

```
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    public ReportController(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
     var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Project\ReportDlls");
     var modules = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.dll");
       foreach (var m in modules)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(m.FullName);
            _kernel.Load(assembly);
        }
```

And I Read from kernel with below code but its return null routesProviders....Why??

```
       var routesProviders = _kernel.GetAll<IReport>();
            foreach (var rp in routesProviders)
            {
                if (rp.GetType().Name == "DailyResult")
                {
                    var f = rp.GetType();
                }
            }
```

My Interface is IReport and My Dll Derived from IReport and In class IocModule in my dll i wrote  `Kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<DailyResult>();`
But Its Not work....???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Load()` of the IKernel extension, search for public's INinjectModule's in the assemblies that you passed, and invoke the concrete `Load()` method, so you must to include in any assembly that you passed some INinjectModule that make the bind `Kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<DailyResult>();` in *Load* method.
See the reference: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel

Or you can do something like that

```
 var types= typeof(SomeClassInTheAssembly).Assembly;
        kernel.Bind(syntax => syntax.From(types)
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .BindDefaultInterface()
            .Configure(config => config.InRequestScope()));
```

instead `_kernel.Load(assembly);`.

Hope be useful X)